# Lightning Component configuration property with a datasource as "required" causes an UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION when deploying

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, dynamic-picklist

I have a Lightning Web Component with a property in its target config that looks like this:

```xml
<property name="companyRecordTypeId" type="String" label="Company Record Type" required="true" datasource="apex://CompanyRecordTypePicklist" />
```

If I attempt to deploy it to my org I get this response:

```
Starting SFDX: Deploy Source to Org

11:09:08.857 sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath c:\workspace\...\force-app\main\default\lwc\myComponent\myComponent.js-meta.xml --json --loglevel fatal
11:09:12.184 sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath c:\workspace\...\force-app\main\default\lwc\myComponent\myComponent.js-meta.xml --json --loglevel fatal ended with exit code 1

=== Deploy Errors
PROJECT PATH  ERRORS                 
────────────  ───────────────────────
N/A           UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION (0:0)
```

Are properties with datasources not allowed to be required?

Apex for the picklist below:

```
global class CompanyRecordTypePicklist extends VisualEditor.DynamicPickList {

    global override VisualEditor.DataRow getDefaultValue() {
        return new VisualEditor.DataRow('-- NONE --', '');
    }

    global override VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows getValues() {
        VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows opts = new VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows();
        Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordTypeMap = Schema.SObjectType.Company__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName();
        RecordTypeInfo rti;

        for(String key : recordTypeMap.keySet()) {
            rti = recordTypeMap.get(key);
            if(rti.isActive()) {
                opts.addRow(new VisualEditor.DataRow(rti.getName(), String.valueOf(rti.getRecordTypeId())));
            }
        }

        return opts;
    }


}
```

**EDIT**: It's worth noting that if I return any of the record types in `getDefaultValue()` the same error happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to stem entirely from making an attribute `required` while also providing a `datasource`. There is no way to make the field required if the values come from a datasource.